# How can I build android on my debian while using eclipse ? (java dependencies problem)

Tags: debian, java, android, eclipse

I would like to compile a build for my android device (N4) with my debian (jessie).

I read that I must have Java 6, but eclipse which I sometimes use seems to need java 7.

For example, I uninstalled java so eclipse, then installed openjdk-6, at this point I have 1.6 java version but reinstalling eclipse update it to 1.7 !

What did I miss ?

Comment: Wait, what is your *right now* problem? IMO, you just have to install Eclipse with apt and should be ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're fine using java 7 to compile java 6 sources, it's backward compatible.  If you are using the android plug-in with eclipse, you should get warnings for using java 7 features, and at any rate, when you go to compile any 1.7 specific code (for each loops, `<>`, etc.), you'll get an error.  These are mostly trivial things that are easy to correct.

So when it says you must have java 6, what it means is you must have *at least* java 6.  I use 7 to compile android stuff.

Comment: Well maybe you understood that I wanted to compile an app, but I want to compile a ROM, android itself, and Google clearly says that it needs to be built with java 6. Anyway I tried and I'm getting an error apparently linked to java 7 (https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/DyLf_14kLeU)
I guess that there's something I don't know how to do, but what ? Force eclipse installation without its dependancies ?

Comment: Found a solution, java version was not the problem, sorry ^^